# Swift: Tap on a textField to start an action

Tags: swift2

In my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func textField(sender: AnyObject) {

    if textField.text != "" {
        let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Chat")
        newSweet["content"] = textField.text
        textField.delegate = self
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.sweets.insert(newSweet, atIndex: 0)
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:
                        .Top)
                    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

                        return true
                    }})

            }else{
                print(error)
                }
        })
   }
}
```

I am trying to access `cloudKit` so when you type something in the `UITextField` it activates the `UITextField` `@IBAction`.
What happens now when I enter text in the `UITextField` nothing happens so I need it to activate the `@IBAction`. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You should use TextFieldDelegate's function to do it

Answer (score 4):

In your `ViewController`, import protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

in your `viewDidLoad` do like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self 
}
```

And you must install delegate method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
        let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Chat")
        newSweet["content"] = textField.text
        textField.delegate = self
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.sweets.insert(newSweet, atIndex: 0)
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:
                        .Top)
                    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

                        return true
                    }})

}
```

If you want to click `Return` on the `Keyboard` will dismiss the keyboard, you have to install this `TextFieldDelegate` method

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I replaced the other @IBAction with func textFieldDidBeginEditing

Comment: You want to click enter will dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: Yea and for the action to go through right now still nothing happens.

Comment: It should self.textField.resignFirstResponder() not textField.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: @khuong291 no it doesn't

Comment: @khuong291 nothing happens

Comment: weird, is your textField name "textField"??

Comment: Oh no, you should put this function textFieldShouldReturn  out side textFieldDidBeginEditing @_@

Comment: @khuong291it is inside

Comment: put it inside viewController and out side textFieldDidBeginEditing, surely it will work. If it work, please mark my answer as the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: I told you remove the textFieldShouldReturn inside the textFieldDidBeginEditing, just put it out side

Comment: @khuong291 I did put it on the outside not the inside still doesn't work why? [link] (http://imgur.com/wt1wUaC)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107883/discussion-between-khuong291-and-elia-baitel).

Comment: Please add my Skype: khuongphamdang, I will help you easily :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate  //set delegate to class 

@IBOutlet var txtValue: UITextField             //create a textfile variable 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtValue.delegate = self                  //set delegate to textfile
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method

let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Chat")
        newSweet["content"] = textField.text
        textField.delegate = self
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.sweets.insert(newSweet, atIndex: 0)
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:
                        .Top)
                func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()

                    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Comment: It does not work I did exactly what you did but when I press enter nothing happens

Comment: can we do a chat so you can help me?